# Higher performance and lower system impact for dynamically changing WoComerce prices (WP + Elementor)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Here a student group with business and it guys. We inherit a toy platform build on WP + WoComerce + Elementor to play stockmarket, last year someone update the prices manually every time to time, but this year game we want to upgrade to more real scenario and change them continually based of external prices.

External data gathering is in place (on a different machine), now looking for options to update WP-Wocomerce prices with less impact on performance (server is in little cloud machine, provider by sponsor, free of charge but 1procesor and 1gb ram, and not in scope to update/change, as sponsor would angry, maybe next year). Performance is not extremely critic, but not to oversee, there could be up to 200 user concurrently. We have a bunch of "products" (30) so we do not mind some manual self made code.

we see those approaches for the prices it self:

```
if($productd->id==33){
    $price = round($newprice33, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

PHP build up plugging, getting prices i.e. form local file, changing every time user load page: First test show quite a impact, plenty of warning lines in logs

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = price_value 
   WHERE post_id = newPrice33 AND meta_key = '_sale_price';
```

Direct update on DB, really fast, but worries about system-resources hit, not sure if wp-database is thought-out to be supporting that short of open hearth updates.

**What would be the approach with less system impact on performance and resource consumption?**

As for the "external injection of prices", we consider directly changing the DB from the remote machine (external MySQL access), or dropping a file via ftp, and a cron with the MySQL stuff.

**What approach will hit with lower performance loss?**

Any other recommendation will be also appreciated.

Comment: You use transients to store (cache) the price data instead of hitting the DB each time. Furthermore you can set an expirely time so thatdepending on how often you are updating the prices from your external source. More info and how,  see here: https://wpengine.com/resources/guide-to-transients-in-wordpress/

Comment: woocomerce will run faster with some index changes; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: aside of index, of course, my issue is the need of every few minutes price change (sometime we do every minute, sometimes every five or ten minutes)

Comment: Any recommendations ??